# AngularJS [$injector:itkn] Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got function

Tags: angularjs

I am somewhat new to using AngularJS and I need to add a new function to the app, which includes uploading attachments to a folder on the server.  When I go to add the function listed after the "requisition" parameter in the controller, I get the error message in the title of this post which points to the requisition function.

If I had to guess as to why this is happening, I would say it is because the controller has one more parameter than the requisition function, but I don't know enough about Angular's structure to know for sure. From all of the posts that I have read on this error message, it usually comes from an added ',' in the parameters but I don't think that is the case this time.

**Javascript:**

```
var controllerId = 'requisition';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['routemediator', 'common', 'datacontext', '$scope', 'bootstrap.dialog', '$routeParams', '$location', '$window', '$uibModalStack', 'Upload', requisition, function ($scope, Upload) {
    // upload later on form submit or something similar
    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
            $scope.upload($scope.file);
        }
    };

    // upload on file select or drop
    $scope.upload = function (file) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'upload/url',
            data: { file: file, 'username': $scope.username }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
        }, function (resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
        });
    };
}]);
```

**Where the error occurs:**

```
function requisition(routemediator, common, datacontext, $scope, bsDialog, $routeParams, $location, $window, $uibModalStack, Upload) {
*lots of code....*
}
```

Comment: The error is quite explicit, you cannot inject a function to your controller. Try to make it a service ?

Comment: remove `function ($scope, Upload)` from controller initialisation, you are already passing `requisition` function with all of the injections into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `function ($scope, Upload)` from controller initialization.

```
var controllerId = 'requisition';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['routemediator', 'common', 'datacontext', '$scope', 'bootstrap.dialog', '$routeParams', '$location', '$window', '$uibModalStack', 'Upload', requisition]);
```

Add code of `function ($scope, Upload)` in `function requisition` like below

```
function requisition(routemediator, common, datacontext, $scope, bsDialog, $routeParams, $location, $window, $uibModalStack, Upload) {
 // upload later on form submit or something similar
        $scope.submit = function () {
            if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
                $scope.upload($scope.file);
            }
        };

        // upload on file select or drop
        $scope.upload = function (file) {
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'upload/url',
                data: { file: file, 'username': $scope.username }
            }).then(function (resp) {
                console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
            }, function (resp) {
                console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
            }, function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
            });
        };
*lots of code....*
}
```